# Yii and AngularJS Captcha

Tags: angularjs, yii

Is there a way to use the Yii Captcha in AngularJS? I'm having a trouble rendering it on my Yii page. I tried rendering items on a page with the {Yii} keyword with no success.

Comment: Why do you use Yii & AngularJS? Do you really need a *Server-Side* and a *Client-Side* backend for your Application?